# If-else working, switch not

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

I am making an app that has a grid of images with text and each one opens a different activity. It works fine but just for design purposes I want to replace my `if-else statements` with `switch statements` (which I assume I can do) however it doesn't work. Right now my working code to set the label on each image is:

```
if(position == 0)
        textView.setText(R.string.zero);
    else if(position == 1)
        textView.setText(R.string.one);
    else if(position == 2)
        textView.setText(R.string.two);
    else if(position == 3)
        textView.setText(R.string.three);
    else if(position == 4)
        textView.setText(R.string.four);
    else if(position == 5)
        textView.setText(R.string.five);
ect....
```

I want to use:

```
switch(position)
case 0:
   textView.setText(R.string.zero);    
case 1:
   textView.setText(R.string.one);
case 2:
   textView.setText(R.string.two);    
case 3:
   textView.setText(R.string.three);
case 4:
   textView.setText(R.string.four);
```

but when I did that ever label was the last one that I defined (in my example it would be "four"). I also have a similar code for each object to start a different `intent` with the `position` variable however that does the opposite and makes every intent equal to the first one. Is my syntax wrong or will this not work for my situation?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to `break;` after each statement in a `case`, otherwise execution flows down (all cases below the one you want will also get called), so you'll always get the last case.

```
switch(position) {
case 0:
    textView.setText(R.string.zero); 
    break; 
case 1:
    textView.setText(R.string.one);
    break; 
case 2:
    textView.setText(R.string.two);   
    break;  
case 3:
    textView.setText(R.string.three);
    break; 
case 4:
    textView.setText(R.string.four); 
    break; 
}
```

Here's the [official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) explaining when to and when not to use `break;`.

Answer (score 16):

You need to `break;` after each branch:

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        textView.setText(R.string.zero);
        break; // <-- here
    // etc
}
```

Legitimate uses of `switch` when you don't `break` exist, those are called fall throughs; or because you `return` or `throw`.:

```
switch (someNumber) {
    case 0:
        return 0; 
        // no need for break here
    case 1:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        // no need to break here
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Oh, I got two!");
        // fall through
    case 3:
        return 3;
    default:
        System.out.println("Meh")
        // No need to break: last possible branch
}

return -1;
```

will return 3 even if you enter 2.

But otherwise you need to `break`.

Comment: It's always a good pattern to put a break at the end of the default: since someone could add another case below it and get an unexpected fall through.

Answer (score 9):

Using a break statement after each case should fix the problem.  I would also use a default statement as well after the last case.

Answer (score 7):

This is the solution. You need to use `break` to avoid going through each case:

```
switch(position)
case 0:
   textView.setText(R.string.zero);    
   break;
case 1:
   textView.setText(R.string.one);
   break;
case 2:
   textView.setText(R.string.two);  
   break;  
case 3:
   textView.setText(R.string.three);
   break;
case 4:
   textView.setText(R.string.four);    
   break;
```

I would recommend to read the oracle documentation about the [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use break statement after eace case operations. In a switch-case statement if you dont use a break statement then all the cases after that specific one will be executed also

```
case 0:
   textView.setText(R.string.zero);    
   break;
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to put `break;` after each case: like that:

```
switch(position){
case 0:
   textView.setText(R.string.zero);    
   break;
case 1:
   textView.setText(R.string.one);
   break;
case 2:
   textView.setText(R.string.two);    
   break;
case 3:
   textView.setText(R.string.three);
   break;
case 4:
   textView.setText(R.string.four);  
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the **Switch-case** statements, you need to put **break;** after each **case**.

```
switch(position){
case 0:
   textView.setText(R.string.zero);    
   break;
case 1:
  textView.setText(R.string.one);
  break;
case 2:
  textView.setText(R.string.two);    
  break;
case 3:
  textView.setText(R.string.three);
  break;
case 4:
  textView.setText(R.string.four);  
  break;
default:
    System.out.println("not available");
}
```

Also you need to put **default:** at last, because when all case are wrong that time perform default: action.

In the **switch-case** statement not forgot about break; and default action.

Comment: It's always a good pattern to put a break at the end of the default: since someone could add another case below it and get an unexpected fall through.

Answer (score 1):

Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Switch is faster than if-else statement

Bottom line : Default is optional(works like else statement in switch), Break is mandatory.

Interesting fact: you won't see any compilation error, even if you forgot to place the break statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` needs a `break` with in each case. But in your case it could be done much simpler by defining an array as shown below.

```
String values = {R.string.zero, R.string.one, R.string.two, ... };
```

Use this to populate textView : `textView.setText(values[position]);`